# Отправка email и вложенным файлом

Tags: c#, email, gmail

Есть картинка и ее нужно отправить по мылу на gmail, есть предложение?

UPD: Возникает ошибка "Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное соединение, или подлинность клиента не была установлена"

Comment: @АндрейNOP Через SmtpClient, но вроде там нету отправки

Comment: Спасибо, все нашел Вот, кому интересно: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/